# Can we use variable in a object property?

Tags: reactjs

I am setting up a object value by using variable. It's not working.

Name is accessible here but can we access the value here as we accessed the name?

```
const name = 'something';
const value = 'something';
this.setState({ [name]: this.data.[value] });
```

Comment: `this.setState({ [name]: this.data[value] });`?

Comment: const type = this.state.currentEditBox;
        
this.setState({
    profileData: {  
        [type]: this.state.profileData.[type].concat([{name: "", description:"", year:""}])
    }
});
Here type before 'concat' is not evaluating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `.` before your `[]` and it should work:

```
this.setState({ [name]: this.data[value] });
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Syntax.